# Is it possible to create a webpart that works in all SharePoint pages/subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm creating a webpart for SharePoint 2010 that needs to track info accross the whole site. So, is it possible to make it work in every page within the SP site, including existing and future pages that will be created by users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what you are trying to achieve ?

- Create a web control and include it in your master page.
- Or, do your processing in a HTTP Handler.

Comment: I'll try the web control at the master page. Thanks.